# Hardware RAID 0 without OS re-installation

Tags: raid-0, stripe

1. I have Ubuntu & Windows 7 installed on my hdd. Can I mirror the image of the hdd to the second identical drive?  Is this not recommended (i.e have to re-install every OS)? If it is okay to mirror, is there anything else to do to make hw RAID 0 work?
2. Does RAID 0 have the same risk as a single drive?
3. What sector size would you recommend for read/write/extract video files (mostly each around 2 GB)?

Comment: Do you want [RAID 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0) (striping) or [RAID 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1) (mirroring)? The answers are completely different, and if you're confused about what you're doing, now is the time to dispel the confusion.

Comment: @Gilles: RAID 0 (striping) is what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No.  You cannot do this without reinstalling (or moving your data temporarily, setting up RAID, then moving it back).  If you were doing RAID 1, you *might* be able to do it, if you have a fancy enough RAID controller, but even then it's doubtful.
2. No, RAID 0 has higher risk than a single drive, and for pretty obvious reasons.  Suppose that one drive has a 10% chance of failure over the course of a year (that's an unrealistically high failure rate, but it's a convenient number).  That means that in a given year 1/10 drives will fail.  Now, if you add a second drive to a RAID 0 configuration, then you have a 2/10 chance that at least one drive will fail in that year--so you've effectively doubled your failure rate.  A third drive brings that up to 3/10, and so on.
3. For video files, I wouldn't recommend RAID 0 at all, because speed is not important and, as explained above, you double your failure rate. Instead, I would just use two drives.  (I might use LVM if I were only using Linux, but that's not much of an option with Windows).